# xPath - How to add a condition to a node's parent?

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements, parent-child

I'm trying to add a condition to a node's parent, and I can't get it to work.

I only want the nodes having a certain class, but also for which the parent has also a certain class, like :

```
//*[@class='price' and parent@class='special-price']
```

Does someone have an idea on how to add conditions on parents too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `//*p[@class = 'special-price']/*[@class = 'price']` or `//*[@class = 'price' and ../@class = 'special-price']`.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your answer!
The 2nd one does work just fine for me. I found the following way too, but yours is much shorter.

    parent::node()[@class='price-box']

Answer (score 2):

```
//*[@class='special-price']/*[@class='price']
```

If you're searching the whole document anyway, then filter the parents en route to the children, rather than selecting the children and then going back up to check the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do need to select the children and then go back in a certain case. This is what worked for me : 

(..)//*[@class='old-price' or @class='price-excluding-tax' and ../@class='price-box'](..)